# Listview relativelayout simpleadapter not working

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-relativelayout, simpleadapter

I am trying to display some items in a listview, which is located in a relativelayout.
The whole layout is located in one xml file (main.xml)

The layout has also 2 buttons and 2 more textfields (EditText).

I can`t get it to work, as:

1. The listview does not show the items
2. If the listview expands, it duplicates the buttons and textfields present in the layout

can someone please help me?

Here is a part of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/kpnback">

 <EditText 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="110dp" 
  android:id="@+id/editText1"
  android:text="edit1"
  android:inputType="textMultiLine"
  android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_top">
 </EditText> 

 <EditText 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:layout_width="110dp" 
  android:id="@+id/editText2" 
  android:text="edit2"
  android:inputType="textMultiLine"
  android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/lbl_top">
 </EditText> 

 <ListView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="20dp"
  android:id="@+id/kpn" 
  android:layout_y="350dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editText1">
 </ListView> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code for the simpleadapter:

```
@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
        // create the grid item mapping
        ListView kp = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.kpn);

        String[] from = new String[] {"col_1", "col_2"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.editText1, R.id.editText1 };

        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(kpn);
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(0)");
        Elements tdsFromSecondColumn1 = doc.select("table.personaltable td:eq(1)"); 

        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn : tdsFromSecondColumn) {
            map.put("col_1", tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 
            fillMaps.add(map);

            System.out.println(tdFromSecondColumn.text()); 

        } 
        for (Element tdFromSecondColumn1 : tdsFromSecondColumn1) {
            map.put("col_2", tdFromSecondColumn1.text());
            fillMaps.add(map);

            System.out.println(tdFromSecondColumn1.text());
        }

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidLogin.this, fillMaps, R.layout.main, from, to); 
        kp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Do not use "@+id/..." for the layout_below attribute.. Instead use "@id/..."

2) lbl_top is not present inside the RelativeLayout..

3) You'll have to specify layout_toLeftOf or layout_toRightOf, apart from specifying layout_below.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Hi c05mic,
Point 1: corrected.
Point 2: lbl_top is present in relativelayout, only not included in code example.
Point 3: Could you give an example related to my code? I don`t know what you mean exactly.
Do i have to do this for all the items?
Thx.

Comment: <EditText 
  android:id="@+id/editText1"
  android:layout_below="@id/lbl_top">
 </EditText> 

 <EditText 
  android:id="@+id/editText2" 
  android:text="edit2" //take out the margin here.. 
  android:inputType="textMultiLine"
  android:layout_below="@id/lbl_top" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText1>
 </EditText> 

 <ListView 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="20dp"
  android:id="@+id/kpn" 
  android:layout_y="350dp"
  android:layout_below="@+id/editText1">
 </ListView>    Only the relevant attributes are there above.. Hope this helps..